# Reading File Byte by Byte, gives corrupt data

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, readfile

So I was trying to write a C++ program that reads an entire file to the memory (binary).
the memory block is obviously a char array. File reading is successful, but when I loop through the values, some of them are not bytes, like 4294967295.

I really searched and tried everything, but nothing works.
It's worth mentioning that I don't have this problem when reading a file (which is text).

here is the code:

```
char* XFile;
ifstream::pos_type Size;

bool LoadFile(string FileName)
{
    cout << "Opening File: " << FileName << endl;
    ifstream FS(FileName.c_str(),ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);

    if (!FS.is_open())
        return false;

    Size = FS.tellg();
    cout << "File Size: " << Size << " bytes" << endl;
    XFile = new char[Size];
    FS.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    FS.read(XFile,Size);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // This loop is to test the read bytes (for example purposes)
        cout << static_cast<unsigned>(XFile[i]) << "\n";

    FS.close();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: One thing might be important to mention, I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and g++ 4.7

Comment: what is `sizeof(unsigned)` I don't think you're getting a char there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of:

```
 char* XFile;
```

and

```
 static_cast<unsigned>(XFile[i])
```

will cause `XFile[i]` to first be converted to a signed `int`, then cast to an `unsigned`. So if the value in your file is greater than 127, it will become a negative integer value, which is then displayed as a very large positive value. You could change the `char *` to `unsigned char *` and solve the problem, or you could cast it in two phases:

```
 static_cast<unsigned>(static_cast<unsigned char>(Xfile[i]))
```

Note that this is a case of "when converting the data into a different representation" the value is being corrupted, your data actually read from the file is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Default `char` can be either signed or unsigned. On your platform, it's apparently signed, and `static_cast<unsigned>` converts negative numbers to a large positive number. Use `unsigned char` for your buffer instead of `char`.